# JavaScript: How to store array[char] values into a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, converters

I am writing a decimal to binary converter in javascript and i have this issue.

Here is my code.

```
function binaryConverter(x)
    {
        if(x === "")
        {
            return 0;
        }

        let binaryArray = new Array(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);
        let result = new Array();
        let newX;

        //pelda: x = 75

        for(let i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++)
        {

            if(binaryArray[i] <= x)
            {
                result.push('1');
                newX = x - binaryArray[i]; // 75 - 64 = 11 | 11 - 8 = 3 | 3 - 2 = 1
                x = newX;

            }
            else
            {
                result.push('0');
            }
        }

        writeBinaryNumber(result);

    }

function writeBinaryNumber(ar)
    {


        for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
        {
            document.write(ar[i]);
        }
    }
```

With document.write() it is works(I only tested it with number 75, i know the first part of binary code is 0, i will fix it.). But i want to connect with my html. I would like to return a variable which contains the chars which is in the array but i can't. In C++ with iterators it is working but i am not familiar with javascript and i used google to search about solution but i couldn't find. If somebody know the solution please write it down! Thanks!

Comment: you need to display with in html right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array `join()` method to concatenate all the strings in an array into a single string.

```
let binaryString = ar.join('');
```

You could also just concatenate to a string instead of creating an array.

```js
function binaryConverter(x) {
  if (x === "") {
    return 0;
  }

  let binaryArray = new Array(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);
  let result = '';
  let newX;

  //pelda: x = 75

  for (let i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++) {

    if (binaryArray[i] <= x) {
      result += '1'
      newX = x - binaryArray[i]; // 75 - 64 = 11 | 11 - 8 = 3 | 3 - 2 = 1
      x = newX;

    } else {
      result += '0';
    }
  }

  return result;
}

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var input = parseInt(this.value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = binaryConverter(input);
})
```

```html
Enter number: <input id="input"> 
<br>
Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ar.join('')
```

```js
function binaryConverter(x) {
  if (x === "") {
    return 0;
  }

  let binaryArray = new Array(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);
  let result = new Array();
  let newX;

  //pelda: x = 75

  for (let i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++) {

    if (binaryArray[i] <= x) {
      result.push('1');
      newX = x - binaryArray[i]; // 75 - 64 = 11 | 11 - 8 = 3 | 3 - 2 = 1
      x = newX;

    } else {
      result.push('0');
    }
  }

  writeBinaryNumber(result);

}
binaryConverter(75)
function writeBinaryNumber(ar) {
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ar.join('')
}
```

```css
#demo{
 color:red
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" ></p>
```